# Is it possible to dynamically resize the height of a page embedded Visual Force page?

Tags: visualforce

I have a Visual Force page that has different amounts of content based on how much information is entered into the controlling fields. Instead of setting a static height, I'd like to be able to dynamically resize it. If I compensate by adding more height than I need to, it'll display a huge white gap between the fields and the Visual Force page, and if I adjust it to a smaller height, it won't display everything entered into the fields. Please see code below:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Medical_Renewal__c"  showheader="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false"  applyBodyTag="false">
<head>
<style>
h1{font-size:35;color:#b20000;}
td{text-align:left;font-size:17px;width:25%}
</style>


  <title>CHARTALERTS</title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%">



    <tr><td style="text-align:right"><b>Patient Name:</b></td><td style="text-align:left"><apex:outputField value="{!Medical_Renewal__c.Patient_Chart__r.Patient_Name__c}"/></td><td style="text-align:right">&nbsp;</td><td style="text-align:left">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td style="text-align:right"> <b>Date of Birth:</b></td><td style="text-align:left"><apex:outputField value="{!Medical_Renewal__c.Patient_Chart__r.Date_of_Birth__c}"/> </td><td style="text-align:right"><b>Medications :</b></td><td style="text-align:left"><apex:outputField value="{!Medical_Renewal__c.Patient_Chart__r.Medications__c}"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="text-align:right"><b>Patient Age:</b></td><td style="text-align:left"><apex:outputField value="{!Medical_Renewal__c.Patient_Chart__r.Age__c}"/></td><td style="text-align:right"><b>Previous Hair Transplant :</b></td><td style="text-align:left"><apex:outputField value="{!Medical_Renewal__c.Patient_Chart__r.Previous_Hair_Transplant__c}"/></td> </tr>
    <tr><td style="text-align:right"><b>Allergies: </b></td><td style="text-align:left"><apex:outputField value="{!Medical_Renewal__c.Patient_Chart__r.Allergies__c}"/></td><td style="text-align:right"><b>Medical History:</b></td><td style="text-align:left"><apex:outputField value="{!Medical_Renewal__c.Patient_Chart__r.Medical_History__c}"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="text-align: right"><b>Comments: </b></td><td style="text-align: left" colspan="2"><apex:outputField value="{!Medical_Renewal__c.Patient_chart__r.Comments__c}"/>&nbsp;<apex:outputField value="{!Medical_Renewal__c.Patient_chart__r.Comment__c}"/></td></tr>

  </table>

</body>


</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Whether you're talking about Classic or Lightning, there is no currently supported way to alter the size of the embedded frame dynamically. You'll need to deal with having too much space, or too little. One technical alternative you might consider is a custom link to display the page in its own window, and in Lightning, you could create a Record Page and add this page to its own tab, so at least the wasted space will be less obvious.